# Multiple vue instances inside js file error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm creating a multiple instances of vue in my app.js file, the `#app` instance if for my admin side (admin panel) and the `#roadmap` instance is for the landing page for specifically for the roadmap component. It works  but when I check the console it shows me `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`. Is this the right way to do it? Am I wrong? Whats the problem.

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
})


const roadmap = new Vue({
    el: '#roadmap',
    router
})
```

Comment: When this code runs, there is no element available within the document with `id="app"` so Vue cannot bind itself to a root element.

Comment: Any ideas how can I solve the error sir? Should I ignore the error since it works?

Comment: I guarantee it doesn't work. I certainly wouldn't have two route-able Vue apps running on the same page though since there's only one location to monitor. Your question is too broad to answer categorically. Could you perhaps provide more detail?

Comment: I have an admin panel of my website sir and it has its own components like adding news and some stuff and it has its own vue-routes then I have this landing page which outputs the news and other stuff that I created from the admin panel. I'm done with the admin panel so that I tried to use vue in the landing page and make output the stuff from my admin using new components for the landing page. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the second `div` in the `public/index.html`.

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="roadmap"></div>
```